# Concatenating a string to the result of input()

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I want to do something like this in command line:

```
Enter input filename: filename
```

When user specifies the filename, this should happen

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('filename.txt')]
```

I tried using

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('input().txt')]
```

But it just looks for a file with name 'input().txt'

How can i make this work?

Thanks

Comment: open('input().txt') - huh? ever heard of the difference between variables and strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `input()` to be outside of the quotes, and then concatenate it with the `'.txt'` using the `+` operator. Additionally, it would increase the clarity of your code to get the filename, open the file, and read the file on separate lines.

```
filename = input()
with open(filename + '.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Also, if you're not using Python 3, you probably mean `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Hi, It works when i run the program in shell, but when i try to run it in command line it's generating an error. Could you please tell me Why it runs in shell but not in command line.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually getting an error? It could just be doing what it's supposed to do very fast.

Comment: IOError: (errno 22) Invalid argument data\r.txt

Comment: @Jay Try entering `data/r.txt`

Comment: Hi, apparently its a known bug in version 32. carriage return added to end of input string. It Works now after i added rstrip()

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting the string:

```
open('{0}.txt'.format(input(), 'r'))
```

You cannot call a function from directly inside of a string, so you must call the function first and then generate the string around the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lines = [ line.strip() for line in open(raw_input("Enter input filename: ")) ]
```